# preg_match_all to return all lines that match, and exclude the pattern that was matched on

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm processing a large chunk of data, and am trying to return all the lines within it that contain the string "INFO:".  I've managed to get the pattern to return the data that I'm interested in, but wanted to know how to improve this regex pattern to omit the string that I'm matching (as well as the white space if possible), so that only the actual data I'm interested in is returned.

```
$pattern = "/^.*INFO:.*\$/m";
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);

INFO:   framerate             25.00
INFO:   width                 480.00
INFO:   height                360.00
INFO:   audioinputvolume      75.00
INFO:   audiocodecid          mp4a
INFO:   audiodatarate         48.00
```

Comment: If this is a tab delimited file (which it appears to be) it would be far better to explode the string and get the fields than to use a regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the groups you are interested in matching in a [subpattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) `( )`

I think in your case it would look like:

```
$pattern = "/^.*INFO:(.*)\$/m";
```

Now you can see the contents of what was in the parentheses using `$matches[1][$match]`

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/^INFO:\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)$/ms', $content, $matches);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => INFO:   framerate             25.00
            [1] => INFO:   width                 480.00
            [2] => INFO:   height                360.00
            [3] => INFO:   audioinputvolume      75.00
            [4] => INFO:   audiocodecid          mp4a
            [5] => INFO:   audiodatarate         48.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => framerate
            [1] => width
            [2] => height
            [3] => audioinputvolume
            [4] => audiocodecid
            [5] => audiodatarate
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25.00
            [1] => 480.00
            [2] => 360.00
            [3] => 75.00
            [4] => mp4a
            [5] => 48.00
        )

)
```

Note that neither field is allowed to have spaces this way.

Comment: +1, but why the `U` modifier? Making the plus lazy doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Actually, that was a remnant from a pattern I tried before, fixed - thanks!

Comment: Not sure what to make of this...I get 3 empty arrays, though the data you're using is a cut/paste of the data I'm usin.g

Comment: Are you sure you're actually having newlines at the end of each line?

Comment: ah...that could be it...it's actually the result of a proc_open that I'm using, so don't *actually know what's being used there for new lines.  My editor interprets whatever is being returned as linefeeds, thus I could cut/paste.

Comment: Well, it probably **are** newlines then, strange. Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere else?

Comment: After this: $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); , i apply the regex against stdout, and get 3 empty arrays.

Comment: @GregP, Does your regex end with `\$`?  That's incorrect, but you got away with it in your original regex because you used double quotes.  If you use single quotes (which you should whenever possible) it tries to match a literal `$`.

Comment: Just cut/pate your answer exactly, with the same result :( ,though I did have the double quotes thing going on.

Comment: @GregP: Just for completeness sake: [My full code @ pastebin, working for me](http://pastebin.com/WMCR7gKX), edit: [and on Ideone](http://ideone.com/HUm7i)

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = "/INFO:\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)(\s|$)/m";
```

That should do the trick. The stuff matched in parentheses will appear as elements in $matches[1] and $matches[2]

Here's what this would output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => INFO:   framerate             25.00

        [1] => INFO:   width                 480.00

        [2] => INFO:   height                360.00

        [3] => INFO:   audioinputvolume      75.00

        [4] => INFO:   audiocodecid          mp4a

        [5] => INFO:   audiodatarate         48.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => framerate
        [1] => width
        [2] => height
        [3] => audioinputvolume
        [4] => audiocodecid
        [5] => audiodatarate
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 25.00
        [1] => 480.00
        [2] => 360.00
        [3] => 75.00
        [4] => mp4a
        [5] => 48.00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 

        [1] => 

        [2] => 

        [3] => 

        [4] => 

        [5] => 
    )

)
```

There is a third array of all the whitespace/end of line characters because I used parentheses in order to use the | operator to say that whitespace OR the end of the text is fine to match.

Comment: Credit for the good answer, but drew010 beat you by a few moments

Comment: That doesn't capture the last `48.00` since there is no whitespace after it.

Comment: I agree, `/^INFO:\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s*$/m` would be better, although both would fail if the first term can contain spaces.

Comment: @TimPietzcker thanks. Looking at it again it really doesn't need the ^ to indicate the beginning of the line so I omitted it. You know, just in case some pesky whitespace appears. ;)

Comment: Also, don't use `$` in a string encapsulated in `"`s, PHP tries to evaluate them.

Comment: @ccKep but the $ is immediately followed by a ) which would be invalid for a variable name. Therefore it won't get parsed I believe. And I slashed it anyway just in case.

Comment: @MichaelTaggart Indeed, it wasn't actual criticism on this string - I meant this more generally. We don't know who's reading this afterall ;) In case you already edited your pattern, it still does not match that 48.00 for me. Edit: Nvm, copied your escaping \ in a ''-encapsulated string.

Comment: @ccKep You are right. I got all spooked with the $ and decided to slash it, but by doing so I'm telling the regex to match a dollar sign and not the end of the line. Taking the slash away makes it work, and this time I actually wrote a script and tested it myself. ;) Thanks for the pointers though. Regexes are so easy to screw up, even the simple ones. (especially when you just type it out on SO without fully testing)